# How to disable shrink and minifyEnabled for specific dependencies

Tags: java, android, flutter, nlp

*How to disable shrink and minifyEnabled for specific dependencies*

I'm working on a sentence detection flutter plugin in Java. It works perfectly in the run, debug, and profile mode, but it fails in release or build mode.

error on release mode

```
I/flutter ( 2762): PlatformException(error, d.a.d.c: Could not instantiate the opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorFactory. The initialization throw an exception., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: d.a.d.c: Could not instantiate the opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorFactory. The initialization throw an exception.
I/flutter ( 2762):      at d.a.d.i.c.j(Unknown Source:31)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at d.a.d.i.c.l(Unknown Source:82)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at d.a.d.i.c.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at d.a.c.g.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at b.a.a.a.b.d(Unknown Source:19)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at b.a.a.a.b.b(Unknown Source:30)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at c.a.c.a.i$a.a(Unknown Source:17)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.e.b.c(Unknown Source:57)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(Unknown Source:4)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7615)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
I/flutter ( 2762):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$Met
```

In **build.gradle** I found that **if minifyEnabled is true**, the above error appears and when **minifyEnabled and shrink are false** everything works fine.

my java code

```java
  private List<String> processText(String text) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    List<String> sentencesList = Collections.<String>emptyList();
    try {
      inputStream = assetManager.open("opennlp-en-ud-ewt-sentence.bin");
      SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(inputStream);
      SentenceDetectorME sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);
      sentencesList = Arrays.asList(sentenceDetector.sentDetect(text));
      for(String s: sentencesList){
        Log.d("JavaSide", s);
      }
      return Arrays.asList(sentenceDetector.sentDetect(text));

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sentencesList;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the ProGuard renames almost every class.

i added "@Keep" annotation with "Upload" class and my problem was solved.

```
@Keep
public class Upload{
.....
.....
}
```

try this may be works for you